# fancybox2-rails: override styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I want to override the default styling using the fancybox2-rails.  In particular, I want to set the navigation outside the slideshow like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3B2/

Unfortunately, this isn't working with any traditional ways I'm trying, like overriding the css manually in my view:

```
$(function(){
    // override fancybox default styling
    console.log("overriding styling");
    $('.fancybox').css("margin", "20px 60px 20px 60px");
    $('.fancybox-prev').css("left", "-60px");
    $('.fancybox-next').css("right", "-60px");
}
```

In my browser, I can see that the styling is defined in the file jquery.fancybox.css, but I can't access this file.  How might I change the styling?

Comment: why you can't do as in the fiddle? .... you can set those values via css in an additional css file/inline declaration without over complicating things

Comment: I can't really do it in a fiddle because the issue is fundamentally a rails gem issue.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this, I created the file

```
fancybox_and_overrides.css.scss
```

and put it in my stylesheets folder.

I then edited the contents to look like this:

```
.fancybox-prev{
    left:-80px !important;
}

.fancybox-next{
    right:-80px !important;
}

.fancybox-nav{
    width: 60px !important;
}
```

and it worked!